# Spartacus-TUA: Current User undefined at Spartacus Service

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am developing an Spartacus TUA Application and currently I am facing some issue

When Spartacus is performing addCartEntryWithChecklistActions standard function, the current user is set at context.

But when calling the msisdnReservationService, Spartacus looses the reference to the current user.

At first image you can look that the current user is set to tim.james@hybris

[image: Print with current user set]

And at second print the current user is null

[image: Print with current user null]

Comment: What I realized is that Constructor for LogicalResourceReservationService is not setting the currentUser correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking with Spartacus DEV Team via SAP Incidents and found out that is seems to be a OOTB Bug.

So we made an override at this point and now it is working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).